# React Hook Component using old value of state which is passed through useContext

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Please see this sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/use-context-simple-qygdz?file=/src/App.js

*** You have to go to /check1  to start, and when you reach /check2 there shouldn't be a ddd, but it's still there right now (state not updated)

When I've linked one page to another, the usecontext does not pass the state. Not sure why - but I am glad that with help we were able to pinpoint exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it helps if you just use one useState hook from which you update your entire context I included the main parts below (here is a link to a working [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-ride-kukx6?file=/src/App.js:90-103)). When i try this i see context changes in every component.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import ChangeContext from "./components/ChangeContext";
import ViewChange from "./components/ViewChange";

const info = {
  artists: null,
  messages: null,
  songs: null,
  userid: "ddd",
  accesstoken: null,
  refreshtoken: null
};

export const InfoContext = React.createContext();

export default function App() {
  const [context, setContext] = React.useState(info);
  return (
    <InfoContext.Provider value={[context, setContext]}>
      <div className="App">
        <ChangeContext />
        <ViewChange />
      </div>
    </InfoContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

and then in a component

```
import React from "react";
import { InfoContext } from "../App";

export default function App() {
  const [context, setContext] = React.useContext(InfoContext);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{context.userid} uid</h1>
      <button
        onClick={e => {
          setContext({ ...context, userid: 123 });
        }}
      >
        click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

in another component check for changes

```
import React from "react";
import { InfoContext } from "../App";

export default function ChangeContext() {
  const [context, setContext] = React.useContext(InfoContext);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{context.userid} uid</h1>
      <button
        onClick={e => {
          setContext({ ...context, userid: 123 });
        }}
      >
        click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

maybe try this instead

```
const [context, setContext] = useState(info);
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route exact path="/signup/:id/:access_token" render={() => <InfoContext.Provider value={[context, setContext]}><Signup /> </InfoContext.Provider>} />
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Login />} />
      <Route exact path="/home/:id/:access_token/:refresh_token" render={() => <Homepage ></Homepage>} />
      <Route exact path="/artist/:artistid" render={() => <ArtistPage ></ArtistPage>} />
      <Route exact path="/map" render={() => <MapLeaflet />} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
```

Comment: So I redid all of this using what you indicated above, but it still wasn't working. Could you take a look at my git? https://github.com/2022karanbhasin/finalnearify The two files in question are in the client folder and are artisthomepage.js and homepage.js !! Thank you for the help in any case!!

Comment: i added another option which might be to wrap the rendered component in the provider one by one. I tried setting up your app localy to test but it's  not working given the need for tokens and what not.

Comment: Could you give me your email possibly? I don't mind sending it over to you as a ZIP.

Comment: So I looked more into your code template and when I tried to do it while still having a browser router and linking the changecontext component so that when you click on the button it changes context and redirects you to the view change context, then it doesn't work--> you can't see the changed context in the view changed context component. @Henri De Bel

Comment: I was able to update the sandbox.io to show the bug/problem! Here it is : https://codesandbox.io/s/use-context-simple-qygdz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i see your using an anchor tag do shouldn't you use a Link component to prevent page refresh ? :)   https://codesandbox.io/s/use-context-simple-vpr5h?file=/src/App.js:156-212

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but is the `userId` being updated in the context?
What is the value for `console.log(userid)` inside **artisthomepage.js**? Maybe it renders with the old value but then it receives the new one and doesn't re-render the component.

Comment: So it's still the old value. This was also when I used the above strategy of having a single context object.

Comment: Here's the sandbox showing the most basic version of the problem:https://codesandbox.io/s/use-context-simple-qygdz?file=/src/App.js